# Moving an azure mounted vhd blob from one storage account to another

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

I have a 3 GB disk mounted to /var/www/ on the same storage account as the OS disk

Because I cannot monitor the size of individual disks in Azure, rather I can only monitor the size of the blob data in a storage container. I now need to move the 3GB disk that is mounted on /var/www/ to a new storage container so I can monitor the size of the www directory

How do I do this? and if I can will it break the mount?

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Not sure what your monitoring concern is, but you'd need to:

- unmount the disk
- detach the disk from your VM
- copy the blob (using whatever tool or code you want)
- attach the disk to your VM
- remount the disk

You cannot do anything with the page blob while it's attached to a VM.

Regarding size monitoring: vhd's in page blobs are sparsely-allocated (you're only billed for storage actually used). You could use the OS-based disk-free tools to monitor actual usage.

Comment: Thanks, I need monitoring of second disk in its own storage account for customer billing. When they use there allocated 3 or 10GB of data we need to be told so we can change the plan they are on.